# How to set force-dvi on wayland?

Tags: display, xrandr, wayland, hdmi

While I've figured out how to set a custom resolution on wayland via: https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution, I cannot figure out how to set the wayland equivalent of 'xrandr force-dvi'.

For context this is the script I made to run my second monitor using an HDMI-DVI adapter:

```
#!/bin/bash
#cvt -r 2560 1440 60
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440R"  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 2560x1440R
xrandr --output HDMI1 --set audio force-dvi --mode 2560x1440R
```

I would like to use wayland with my second monitor as-well but cannot figure out how to achieve the same thing as this script in wayland.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (for audio) and I found this: https://github.com/NickCis/drm_tool.
I successfully enabled audio with the following command:

```
$ ./drm_tool set /dev/dri/card0 <connector_id> audio -2
```

[Edit] This works only when switching to console, permission is denied from terminal. I've tried using drmSetMaster() but I surely miss competency on DRM.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, I do not care about audio out. I am specifically trying to set the HDMI to output DVI.

Comment: For me it works, `-2` for DVI output and `0` for HDMI output